# Event handling in creating web pages

Tags: jquery

I am going to create a web page which has a button. If the button is clicked, the user is prompted to enter some text. Unless the user enters an empty string or the character x, or clicks on the Cancel button, the text that was entered is appended as a `<p>` tag with a yellow background to the body of the document.

Below is my code which does not work, can you kindly help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Simple Demo</title>
  <style>
    p {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#myButton").click(function() {
          var message = prompt("Enter some text...");
          if ($(this).data("clicked") == true;) {
            document.write(message);
          } else {
            message === null || message === x || $("#myCancelButton").click(function) {
              $("body").append("<p>" + message "</p>");
            });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="myButton">Click Me!</button>
  <button id="myCancelButton">Cancel!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: define "does not work" first... At first glance though you're checking for `data('clicked')` but there doesn't seem to be any `data-clicked` attribute in the button so I'm not sure if you're certain of what you're actually doing there. Among some other things that don't look quite right

Comment: @lascort: you are right, because what I have to do is kinda confusing to me and I `m not sure if I am on the right path.

Comment: You have syntax errors in your JavaScript. Check the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a mountain out of a molehill here!

1. The built-in prompt has a cancel button already - when the user clicks it, the `prompt` call returns `null`.
2. If you're inside the jquery handler for a button click, then you know that the user has clicked the button.

```js
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  var result = prompt("Enter some text");
  if(result != null && result != "x"){
     $('body').append("<p>" + result + "</p>"); 
  }
});
```

```css
p{
 background-color:yellow;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
```